# Nginx config for subdomain and forum

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I'm trying to configure nginx to do the following:

- redirect example.com and www.example.com to my old website
- www.example.com/forum or example.com/forum to forum webserver (ip)
- any other subdomain to .example.com, reverse proxied to node.js

I know the following does not work, how should I configure?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    location /forum {
        proxy_pass http://<forum ip>/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    return 301 $scheme://www.old-website.com;
}
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name ~^(.*)\.example\.com $;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The naked `return 301` will prevent the `location /forum` block from being considered. Try wrapping it inside a default location block:

```
location /forum {
    ...
}
location / {
    return 301 $scheme://www.old-website.com;
}
```

Comment: When loading forum I'm getting 404 on all static files as they are requested on the naked domain instead of example.com/forum

Comment: Understood. But that is a problem with the application and not your reverse proxy. I do not know how to fix the problem in the reverse proxy. Usually you need to configure the application to request resources with the `/forum` prefix already attached.